# SharePoint 2010 - SPItemEventReceiver initialized 12 times

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 integration that has an SPItemEventReceiver for handling ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events for the Document library list. I have added a constructor to handle some initialization for the event receiver. In testing/debugging I have noticed that when my feature is activated (the feature containing this event receiver) my event receiver is initialized 12 times. I have been trying to figure out why the constructor is called 12 times and wondering if all 12 instances are going to be alive until the feature is deactivated or if I need to be careful as some of them may be garbage collected down the road. Anyone know why there are 12 and what their lifetime is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say the magic number 12 is relevant; it's just scaling for you. Regardless, SharePoint event receivers should not depend on singleton semantics. What's important is that for each unique event, you can be sure that only one of these event receivers will handle the event, unless you accidentally added 12 to the same list ;-)

-Oisin

Comment: So this would probably be the same, even if I added it in my feature activated programmatically as opposed to allowing the "wsp" packaging to handle the deployment. Is there any way to get "singleton" initialization semantics for an event receiver. My goal is to set up some folder watching in another thread.

Comment: I guess another question I should ask is, is you mentioned "SharePoint event receivers should not depend on singleton semantics" is there some documentation along those lines? I am not doubting it, I am new to SharePoint and web style development, I have been doing desktop C++/COM/C# development for several years.

Comment: There isn't any documentation on that particular point for event receivers, but there more you do web development you'll realise it applies to everything. HTTP is stateless, regardless of how ASP.NET uses viewstate to make you think otherwise. Trying to assume that only one person will execute your aspx page at any one time is a good analog. The web is all about parallelism, and this reaches deep into the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I am beginning to understand/see the whole stateless situation, just have to get my mind around developing for it. I have done lots of multi-threaded stuff on the desktop/server side, but the jump into Asp.Net/SharePoint has been a conceptual leap into a new deep/dark pond. I have been able to work around the concept and get a singleton like behavior by creating a lock file on the disk (this is all internal and using a UNC path so it is visible). This allows only 1 thread to actually continue executing. It may be a hack, but it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Droping 12 Files suing explorer view will cause such a affect.

Comment: It would cause 12 added events to fire, but what I am seeing is 12 event receivers having their constructor called, even though for each file drop only 1 event handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to remove the event receiver on feature deactivating. This happens a lot in dev environments, as many people create their activated code in the feature activation, but not the deactivate code and end up with a bunch of receivers on a list, etc.

Comment: The issue was the number of constructor calls for the receivers on the activate, not really orphaned receivers. This is a good practice concept since it is good to remove yourself on deactivate, but deactivation had nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try creating static members in the class, that should get some of what you are after. You'd have to test it though, I can't promise that will work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a sample code for your question if possible to improve the post accuracy and get better results. Have a great day :)